# How to apply background color to unsafe area of iPhone X

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I would like to apply a background color to the unsafe areas of my UIViewController on an iPhone X.  How can I do this in Objective-C?

Comment: unsafe are is part of the view, so you can't separate it from safe area. what you can do is create two custom views, an place them on those unsafe areas

Comment: Maybe start with [Update your apps for iPhone X](https://developer.apple.com/ios/update-apps-for-iphone-x/), [Creating apps for iPhone X](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/), [Development Tutorial for iPhone X](https://www.raywenderlich.com/173928/develop-design-iphone-x), [Updating your app for the iPhone X](https://medium.com/thefork/updating-your-app-for-the-iphone-x-33209fc894d3),

Comment: [How To Solve The Most Common Interface Problems When Adapting Apps UI For iPhone X](https://medium.com/@kahseng.lee123/how-to-solve-the-most-common-interface-problems-when-adapting-apps-ui-for-iphone-x-44c0f3c80d84) for some ideas

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you need to change the background colour of the view itself to match the background colour of something within the view, as follows:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
```